# Form validation with custom update_password method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, devise

I'm working on a form for updating a User's password in my current project. I'm using `Devise`, but because we had to create a custom new User form, I had to also create a custom form for updating passwords. The `update_password` method in my `UsersController` specifies a page redirect if something goes wrong and I'd like to change that so that this update password form more closely matches the create form where error messages are displayed inline. The problem is, if the page redirect is removed I get a `Template is missing` error.

The full error message is this (it's all one line but I broke it up so it's easier to read):

```
Missing template users/update_password, application/update_password with {:locale=>[:en],
:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}.
Searched in: * "/Users/kec6en/HydraApp/fluctus/app/views" * "/Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/hydra-role-management-0.1.0/app/views" *
"/Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views" * 
"/Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/hydra-editor-0.2.2/app/views" *   
"/Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/blacklight-5.0.0.pre4/app/views" * 
"/Users/kec6en/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@fluctus/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
```

This is the form itself:

```
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Change Password</h1>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update_password" } ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password, "New Password" %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off"  %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm New Password" %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :current_password, "Current Password" %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="action_container">
      <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-success") do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i> Submit
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to @user, {class: "btn doc-action-btn btn-cancel"} do %>
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Cancel
      <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the relevant portion of my routes file (just in case):

```
resources :users do
    patch 'update_password', on: :collection
    get 'edit_password', on: :member
  end
```

And this is the relevant portion of the Users Controller (with the redirect commented out):

```
def edit_password
  @user = current_user
end

def update_password
  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully changed password."
  else
    #redirect_to root_path
    flash[:alert] = "Current password was incorrect, new password was too short, or passwords did not match. Password has not been changed."
  end
end
```

Basically, I'd like to change the redirect and flash notice portion in the `else` section to stay on the same page but with the error messages displayed either in a list on top of the form, or next to the relevant form inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use something like

```
render :edit
```

Change `:edit` with whatever view you want to actually show.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to show a different view, I want to be able to use the built in error notifications from the simple form. I don't want the page to redirect at all. But if I remove the redirect statement, things break.